# selected value of second dropdown after clicked on 1st dropdown value is refreshed on add new row in gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, datagridview, autopostback

Hi Friends i am facing a problem in my gridview in asp.net. when  add new row then dropdown value of 1st row refreshed(only those dropdown which are populated OnSelectedIndexChanged of other dropdown).
can anyone please suggest how to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set DropDown.SelectedIndex=0 or -1 on page_load

Answer (score 0):

Your add new row method probably posts back the page. You may need to avoid that in the method properties and add rows asynchornously.

Comment: But it is not clearing all dropdown value. so if add row method postback the page then all dropdown values get clear.

Comment: Would you please post your entire code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object as s, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Ispostback)<br/>
    {
    //here dropdown bind();
    dropdown.SelectedIndex=0; //Set 0 or -1
    }
}
```

Comment: my dropdown is bind OnSelectedIndexChanged of other dropdown

Comment: after your dropdown bind set selectedindex=0 or -1

Comment: protected void drpcompany_indexedchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((DropDownList)sender).Parent.Parent;
        DropDownList ddlpubb = gvr.FindControl("drppub") as DropDownList;
        ddlpubb.DataSource = dspub.Tables[0];
        ddlpubb.DataTextField = "Pub_Name";
        ddlpubb.DataValueField = "Pub_Code";
        ddlpubb.DataBind();
        ddlpubb.SelectedIndex = 0;
        dspub.Clear();

    }

Comment: ddlpubb.Selectedindex=-1 set or SelectedValue="" or null

Comment: declare one Boolean his name like flg = false; and page_load after postback set flg=true; and drpcompany_selectedchanged event set if (flg==true) then execute you code here

Comment: page_load() { if (!Ispostback) { drpcompannybind(); flg=true;  }  } and drpcompany_selectedchanged () { if (flg==true) { // here your code } }

Comment: after using this OnSelectedIndexChanged of drpcompany_selectedchanged my second dropdown is not populate